# PHP Session Array Update

Tags: php, arrays, session

I wish to update a single product quantity from a session with a new value using php.

How can I do this.

Array data is as displayed

```html
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Ford AA Flatbed
                    [code] => IWV001
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 15.00
                    [weight] => 0.12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Ford AA Stakebed
                    [code] => IWV003
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 15.00
                    [weight] => 0.21
                )

        )

)
```

any help would be most appreciated.

I want to be able to search through the session and find the product by code and update the quantity within that product.

Comment: You update a session array just like any other variable. What's the problem you're having? Why can't you search through the array for the product you want and update it?

Comment: Is `array_search` not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
foreach($products as &product) {
    if ($product[code] == $codeToUpdate) {
        $product[qty] = $newQty;
    }
}
```

Of course, this is a sequential search so it will be slow for large data sets.